# What other means are available to crop/clip a background image if :pseudo elements are not available?

Tags: css, background, background-image, pseudo-element

I have a button with multiple backgrounds. One of the backgrounds is a `CSS-sprite` (864px x 18px) containing icons.

I'm trying to add the background to an `<input>` element to make it a button with icon. Problem is, I can't use `:before/:after` because inputs have no content, so I cannot add an element, specify it's proportions and use `background-size/position`.

Here is what I have:

```css
.buttonUpInput {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), #7EB238;
    background-image: none; /* fallback */
    background-image: url("http://mysprite.png"), -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(rgba(52,109,28,1)), color-stop(rgba(52,109,28,0) )), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #9ad945 ), to( #7eb238 )); 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -webkit-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -moz-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -ms-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -o-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(52,109,28,1) 67%, rgba(52,109,28,0) 69%), linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 );
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll, scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: -100px 50%, 7px 50%, center center;
    background-size: 864px 18px, 20px 20px, auto auto;
    background-clip: content-box, content-box, padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: .7em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .7em;
    border-radius: .7em;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 2px 14px 4px 1px;
    text-indent: 35px;
    width: auto;
    height: 2.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Question:**
I could try to hardcode/tweak the button size/width (which I'd prefer being flexible) to try and use `content-box/padding-box`, but I can't get it to work. I'm wondering if there are any other means to achieve this with CSS only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's pretty much nothing you can do to crop a background like that. [SVG sprite stacks](http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks) are about as close as you can get, but support for it is very poor.

However, you could change your input to a button element:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UGwe/

```
button:before {
    content: ' ';
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: yeah. make it a button would be easy :-) Thanks for the SVG tip, I will look into that, too.

Comment: You may want to consider using a specialized sprite sheet that has your icons spaced exceptionally far apart.  SVGs excel in this area, since the file size stays the same no matter what the spacing is like.

Comment: true. I could also make the png go from top>bottom and make sure icons are spaced apart, so the button border will act as "crop" boundary. Still... let's see what else comes up. Thanks again!

Comment: Diagonal sprites may be of interest as well:  http://www.aaronbarker.net/2010/07/diagonal-sprites/

Comment: Got it. Thanks for chipping in :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You can use CSS `box-sizing` which when set to `content-box` maintains the width of an element no matter what padding is added. So the button can be set to icon-size (20x20px), box-sizing to `content-box` thereby cropping the iconsprite beyond 20x20. Then use padding to stretch the button to it's required dimensions.

Example [here](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/css/sample.html)

Code:

```
.icon_text {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), #7EB238;
    background-image: none; /* fallback */
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/icons-18-white.png"), -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(rgba(52,109,28,1)), color-stop(rgba(52,109,28,0) )), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #9ad945 ), to( #7eb238 )); 
background-image: url("url.png"), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -webkit-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("url.png"), -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -moz-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("url.png"), -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -ms-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
background-image: url("url.png"), -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(52,109,28,1), rgba(52,109,28,0) ), -o-linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 ); 
    background-image: url("url.png"), radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(52,109,28,1) 67%, rgba(52,109,28,0) 69%), linear-gradient( #9ad945, #7eb238 );
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll, scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: -100px 50%, 7px 50%, center center;
    background-size: 864px 18px, 20px 20px, auto auto;
    background-clip: content-box, content-box, padding-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;   
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: .7em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .7em;
    border-radius: .7em;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 2.1em;
    /* padding still hardcoded */
    padding: 5px 92px 6px 7px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    }
```